# Do Guice singletons honor thread-confinement?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice

I have a concern regarding Guice and whether or not its singletons will obey thread confinement that I may try to set up:

```
public class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        // WidgetCache.class is located inside a 3rd party JAR that I
        // don't have the ability to modify.
        WidgetCache widgetCache = new WidgetCache(...lots of params);

        // Guice will reuse the same WidgetCache instance over and over across
        // multiple calls to Injector#getInstance(WidgetCache.class);
        bind(WidgetCache.class).toInstance(widgetCache);
    }
}

// CacheAdaptor is the "root" of my dependency tree. All other objects
// are created from it.
public class CacheAdaptor {
    private CacheModule bootstrapper = new CacheModule();

    private WidgetCache widgetCache;

    public CacheAdaptor() {
        super();

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(bootstrapper);

        setWidgetCache(injector.getInstance(WidgetCache.class));
    }

    // ...etc.
}
```

So as you can see, any time we create a new instance of `CacheAdaptor`, a `CacheModule` will be used to bootstrap the entire dependency tree underneath it.

**What happens if `new CacheAdaptor();` is called from inside multiple threads?**

For example: Thread #1 creates a new `CacheAdaptor` via its no-arg constructor, and Thread #2 does the same thing. **Will Guice provide the same exact `WidgetCache` instance to each thread's `CacheAdaptor`, or will Guice provide 2 different instances to each thread?** Even though `toInstance(...)` is supposed to return the same singleton instance, I'm hoping - since the modules are created inside 2 distinct threads - that each `CacheAdaptor` will receive a different `WidgetCache` instance.

Comment: you talk about singleton but i don't see any

Comment: @PhilippSander - `bind(WidgetCache.class).toInstance(widgetCache)` creates a singleton `WidgetCache` instance and then reuses it no matter how many times a client requests it (via `Injector#getInstance(WidgetCache.class)`.

Comment: well you just answered your question...

Comment: Thanks again @PhilippSander - but **did you even read my question?** The question pertains to Guice's behavior across multiple threads. I *know* that, for a single-threaded app, `bind(WidgetCache.class).toInstance(widgetCache)` creates a singleton - **but is that singleton thread-confined or not?** It's very feasible that the `WidgetCache` instance obtained by the module in Thread #1 will be different than the one obtained in Thread #2.

Comment: you were not asking that

Comment: Yes I did - it actually appears in **bold** above, as follows: "**What happens if new CacheAdaptor(); is called from inside multiple threads?**". I always appreciate all input @PhilippSander, but if you don't know the answer to this, I'd ask that you kindly move on to another question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not only that Guice *will* provide the same singleton across threads for the same injector, but Guice *can only* provide the same singleton across threads if you use `toInstance`. Modules are evaluated once per injector, and you gave Guice one instance and no way to produce a second one.

Guice isn't magic. When trying to provide an instance of an Object, it either needs (1) a Guice-friendly no-arg or `@Inject`-annotated constructor; (2) a `Provider` or `@Provides` method, letting you create the instance yourself; or (3) an instance that you've already created and bound with `toInstance`, which Guice reuses because it doesn't know how to create another. Note that option 2, with a `Provider`, doesn't need to guarantee that it creates a new instance every single time, and we can exploit that to write a `Provider` that has a ThreadLocal cache. It would look something like this:

```
public class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {
    /** This isn't needed anymore; the @Provides method below is sufficient. */
    @Override protected void configure() {}

    /** This keeps a WidgetCache per thread and knows how to create a new one. */
    private ThreadLocal<WidgetCache> threadWidgetCache = new ThreadLocal<>() {
        @Override protected WidgetCache initialValue() {
            return new WidgetCache(...lots of params);
        }
    };

    /** Provide a single separate WidgetCache for each thread. */
    @Provides WidgetCache provideWidgetCache() {
        return threadWidgetCache.get();
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want to do that for more than one object, you'd have to write a ThreadLocal for every single key you want to cache, and then create a provider for each. That seems a little excessive, and that's where custom scopes come in.

#### Creating your own ThreadLocal scope

Check out Scope's only meaningful method:

```
/**
 * Scopes a provider. The returned provider returns objects from this scope.
 * If an object does not exist in this scope, the provider can use the given
 * unscoped provider to retrieve one.
 *
 * <p>Scope implementations are strongly encouraged to override
 * {@link Object#toString} in the returned provider and include the backing
 * provider's {@code toString()} output.
 *
 * @param key binding key
 * @param unscoped locates an instance when one doesn't already exist in this
 *  scope.
 * @return a new provider which only delegates to the given unscoped provider
 *  when an instance of the requested object doesn't already exist in this
 *  scope
 */
public <T> Provider<T> scope(Key<T> key, Provider<T> unscoped);
```

As you can see from the [Scope interface](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/source/browse/core/src/com/google/inject/Scope.java), a scope is just a decorator for a `Provider`, and scoping something thread-local is tantamount to returning a `ThreadLocal`-cached copy if it exists or caching and returning from the passed `Provider` if it doesn't. So we can easily write a scope that does the same logic we did manually above.

In fact, the need to create a new FooObject per-thread (for any value of FooObject) is a common request—[too much of an "advanced feature" for the base library](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/issues/detail?id=114), but common enough for it to be the [example about how to write a custom scope](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes#Implementing_Scope). To adjust that SimpleScope example to your needs, you can leave out the `scope.enter()` and `scope.exit()` calls, but keep the `ThreadLocal<Map<Key<?>, Object>>` to act as your thread-local cache of objects.

At that point, assuming you've created your own `@ThreadScoped` annotation with a `ThreadScope` implementation you've written, you can adjust your module to look like this:

```
public class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindScope(ThreadScoped.class, new ThreadScope());
    }

    /** Provide a single separate WidgetCache for each thread. */
    @Provides @ThreadScoped WidgetCache provideWidgetCache() {
        return new WidgetCache(...lots of params);
    }
}
```

Remember, singleton behavior doesn't depend on which threads you create the modules in, but rather which injector you're asking. If you created five unrelated `Injector` instances, they would each have their own singleton. If you're merely trying to run a small algorithm in a multi-threaded way, you could create your own injector per thread, but that way you'd lose the chance to make singleton objects that do span threads.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bowman (+1) - I *think* I'm starting to see the forest through the trees. I have one followup question for you: your second sentence states "*Modules are evaluated once per injector, and you gave Guice one instance and no way to produce a second one.*" **Can you elaborate by what you mean here?** I only gave Guice one instance of *what*? How would I produce a "second one" of it? If you can explain this to me, I should be able to connect all the dots. Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja I ended up refactoring my answer, including a way of doing it in a Provider method manually. Sorry it got much longer but I think it'll better-explain how Guice objects are created and scoped.