# Guice Provider<EntityManager> vs EntityManager

Tags: java, jpa, guice, guice-servlet, guice-persist

I was trying to get simple webapp working with Guice and JPA on Jetty, using the persistence and servlet guice extensions.

I have written this Service implementation class:

```
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService {

private EntityManager em;

@Inject
public PersonServiceImpl(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void savePerson(Person p) {
    em.persist(p);
}

@Override
public Person findPerson(long id) {
    return em.find(Person.class, id);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void deletePerson(Person p) {
    em.remove(p);
}
```

}

And this is my servlet (annotated with @Singleton):

```
@Inject
PersonService personService;

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = req.getParameter("name");
    String password = req.getParameter("password");
    String email = req.getParameter("email");
    int age = Integer.valueOf(req.getParameter("age"));


    Person p = new Person();
    p.setAge(age);
    p.setName(name);
    p.setEmail(email);
    p.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

    logger.info("saving person");

    personService.savePerson(p);
    logger.info("saved person");

    logger.info("extracting person");
    Person person = personService.findPerson(p.getId());
    resp.getWriter().print("Hello " + person.getName());
}
```

When I run this it works, and I get the name sent to the client, but when I look at the log I see that there is no DML generated for the insertion and selection from postgresql does not return any results, which means it wasn't really persisted.

I debugged through the code and I saw that `JpaLocalTxnInterceptor` called `txn.commit()`.

Then I made a change to `PersonServiceImpl` and used `Provider<EntityManager>` instead of just `EntityManager` and it worked as expected. Now I don't really understand why and it's probably because I don't really understand the idea behind Provider.
On the [Guice wiki page](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JPA) it says:

> Note that if you make MyService a @Singleton, then you should inject Provider instead.

However, my PersonServiceImpl is not a @Singleton so I am not sure why it applies, perhaps it's because of the Servlet?

I would really appreciate if you could clear this out for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need `Provider<EntityManager>` because Guice's built-in persistence and servlet extensions expect EntityManager to be request-scoped. By injecting a request-scoped EntityManager from a service held in a singleton servlet, you're making a *scope-widening injection*, and Guice won't store data from a stale, mismatched EntityManager.

### Providers

Provider is a one-method interface that exposes a `get()` method. If you inject a `Provider<Foo>` and then call `get()`, it will return an instance created the same way as if you had injected Foo directly. *However, injecting the Provider allows you to control how many objects are created, and when they are created.* [This can be useful in a few cases:](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingProviders)

- only creating an instance if it's actually needed, especially if the creation takes lots of time or memory
- creating two or more separate instances from within the same component
- deferring creation to an initialization method or separate thread
- mixing scopes, as described below

For binding of `X`, `Provider<X>`, or `@Provides X`, Guice will automatically allow you to inject either `X` or `Provider<X>` directly. You can use Providers without adjusting any of your bindings, and Providers work fine with [binding annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations).

### Scopes and scope-widening injections

Broadly speaking, [scopes](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes) define the lifetime of the object. By default, Guice creates a new object for every injection; by marking an object @Singleton, you instruct Guice to inject the same instance for every injection. Guice's servlet extensions also support @RequestScoped and @SessionScoped injections, which cause the same object to be injected within one request (or session) consistently but for a new object to be injected for a different request (or session). Guice lets you define custom scopes as well, such as [thread scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18601217/1426891) (one instance per thread, but the same instance across injections in the same thread).

```
@Singleton public class YourClass {
  @Inject HttpServletRequest request;  // BAD IDEA
}
```

What happens if you inject a request-scoped object directly from within a @Singleton component? When the singleton is created, it tries to inject the instance relevant to the current request. Note that there might not *be* a current request, but if there is one, the instance will be saved to a field in the singleton. As requests come and go, the singleton is never recreated, and the field is never reassigned--so after the very first request your component stops working properly.

Injecting a narrow-scope object (@RequestScoped) into a wide scope (@Singleton) is known as a *scope-widening injection*. Not all scope-widening injections show symptoms immediately, but all may introduce lingering bugs later.

### How Providers help

PersonService isn't annotated with @Singleton, but because you're injecting and storing an instance in a @Singleton servlet, it might as well be a singleton itself. This means EntityManager also has singleton behavior, for the same reasons.

According to [the page you quoted](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JPA), EntityManager is meant to be short-lived, existing only for the session or request. This allows Guice to auto-commit the transaction when the session or request ends, but reusing the same EntityManager is likely preventing storage of data any time after the first. Switching to a Provider allows you to keep the scope narrow by creating a fresh EntityManager on every request.

(You could also make PersonService a Provider, which would also likely solve the problem, but I think it's better to observe Guice's best practices and keep EntityManager's scope explicitly narrow with a Provider.)